# How to render content of child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular-template

I have 3 components, Tabs, Tab and Toolbar, and using it as follows [Online Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-toolbar):

```
<tabs>
  <tab title="tab 1" active="true">
    <toolbar>Toolbar 1</toolbar>
    Content 1
  </tab>
  <tab title="tab 2">
     <toolbar>Toolbar 2</toolbar>
     Content 2
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

So Tabs has many Tab and Tab has only one Toolbar.

Tabs template is as follows:

```
<div class="head">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="select(tab)" class="tab" [class.active]="tab.active">
      <a>{{ tab.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="toolbar">Toolbar of Active Tab</div>

</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**How to render the Toolbar of the current active Tab in:**

```
<div class="toolbar">Toolbar of Active Tab</div>
```

Each component code is:

```
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {    
  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;    
  select(tab: TabComponent) {
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => { 
      tab.active = false; 
    });
    tab.active = true;
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    let actives = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);
    if(actives.length === 0) 
      this.select(this.tabs.first);
  }
}

export class TabComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;
  @ContentChildren(ToolbarComponent) toolbar: ToolbarComponent;
}

export class ToolbarComponent { }
```

Comment: How about this? https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: I would prefer to solve the problem I posted.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... Looks like the toolbar only is displayed on tab1

Comment: @MCMatan I just updated my question. Both tabs have a toolbar.

Comment: *ngIf might help

Comment: @Antoniossss Sure but how to render the content of the toolbar after the UL with the list of tabs. Maybe I am missing something but I am not sure of how to do this.

Comment: I do not understand the reason for a downvote on this question ... Can someone elucidate me?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, your best 2 option would be:

**Option 1**: Separate toolbar from the tab component, and set Its props with the same way to set props to a tab:

```
<div class="head">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="select(tab)" class="tab" [class.active]="tab.active">
      <a>{{ tab.title }}</a>
      <div class="toolbar">Toolbar of Active Tab {{tab.toolbarTitle}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Option 2**: Pass toolbar props on AppState, that way, the toolbar would be able to access them from anywhere. https://ngrx.io/